# What would be the proper way to listen to a click event over the whole dom with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a calendar with `react`.  It is just a bunch of `li`s.  I want to be able to click on the page and a have a `popover` appear to enter new appointments.  I know that I can use `react-bootstrap` and wrap each `li` in an `OverlayTrigger` and use that to create my `popover`, but this is going to add tons of code to my `dom`.

When we used to use `jQuery`, we would just attach an `event listener` to the `body` and then we could add the `popover` on any `li` that we clicked.

Is there a way to do this without `jQuery`?

Comment: don't you think it's better to restrict the clickable region to some button , say Add appointment button rather than the entire document / body ?

Comment: You can register an event using normal javascript using `document.body.addEventListener('click',function(){ alert('herere');},false);`

Comment: I want my calendar to be lick the Apple or Google calendar.  When you click on the page, it knows the context of the day and hour and you just fill in the appointment info.

Comment: but in Google Calendar, they don't display the pop-up when you click anywhere on the document, it's displayed only when you click on a particular cell - intersection of date and time :)

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do.  When I said click on the document, I meant in one of the cells.  Sorry I didn't make that more clear.

Comment: can you post your sample html containing `li`s inside `ul` ? we can just bind event listener on all `li`s having some class say `cell`, but if you post your HTML, we can see if there's a better way, something like instead of one listener for each `li`, configure a single listener on `ul` but inside the handler, check if the target is a `cell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you just have a bunch of `li`s inside some parent `ul` element, bind an event listener on the parent but in the event handler, check if the actual target that triggered the event is an `li` and act accordingly.

```
<ul id="parent">
  <p>Some para</p>
  <li class="cell 1">Element 1</li>
  <li class="cell 2">Element 2</li>
  <li class="cell 3">Element 3</li>
</ul>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {   
          console.log("List item "+ e.target.className);
      }else{
          console.log('not a list item');
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Here's a [bin](http://jsbin.com/diguceluyo/1/edit?html,output) to play with the approach :)